# How to start app in Zend/MVC with SerciceManager

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I have problem with Dependency Injection in my MVC/Console using Factories

I have created factories

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, 
array $options = null)
{
    return new BaseController($container->get(\Application\Controller\Test::class));
}
```

I inserted in application.config.php

```
return  [     'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        BaseController::class => BaseControllerFactory::class       ],

]]
```

and I start my application like that

```
Application::init($appConfig)->run()
```

I also echoed `$appConfig['service_manager']` and result was:

```
array(10) {
'factories' =>
array(1) {
'Application\Controller\BaseController' =>
string(44) "Application\Controller\BaseControllerFactory"
 }
```

> When I start my application and try to hit the controller the Console
>   says:
>
> ======================================================================    The application has thrown an exception!
>   ======================================================================  ArgumentCountError  Too few arguments to function
>   Application\Controller\BaseController::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   ...\skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\Factory\Invokabl
>   eFactory.php on line 30 and exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds same problem the solution is simple.
In factories section of array 'service_manager' I forgot to mention that class Test has no dependencies so I should have written

```
Test::class => InvokableFactory
```